# Converting two linear 3 variables equations to a single variable(parametric)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Say the two equations are $2x+3y-5z-6=0$ and $3x-2y-z+3=0$.
Had the constants been zero (homogeneous linear equations), I could have used the matrix method and arrive at $x=y=z$. But I don't know how to get these non-homogeneous equations into its parametric form (the constants trouble me).

Comment: Then make the constants 0 and solve the problem that you do know.  For the part you do not know,  find a point that lies on the intersection.  $(x,y,z) = (v_1,v_2,v_2)t + (p_1,p_2,p_3)$.

Comment: Doug M - Damn! I don't think properly when I study late. Thank you so much. Why don't you post this as an answer considering this actually solves my problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then make the constants 0 and solve the problem that you do know. For the part you do not know, find a point that lies on the intersection. 
$(x,y,z)=(v_1,v_2,v_2)t+(p_1,p_2,p_3)$